# Enable automatic image resizing

Tags: html, image

Browsers like IE under Tools, Options, Advanced, have a checkbox for "enable automatic image resizing". Is it correct to say that this feature has nothing to do with the HTML and/or JavaScript on the page itself, and is functionality that the HTML and/or JavaScript on the page itself cannot command?

I ask because I cannot find a way to convince HTML IMG to behave in a manner that resizes by window size which of course can vary with the platform. One can set HTML IMG pixel height and/or pixel width, but that is without respect to the window size. And one can set HTML IMG percent height and/or percent width, but that is with respect to the original image size, not the window size.

I've seen suggestions to box the HTML IMG with a HTML DIV that sets height and/or width limits, but HTML IMG appears to blow out those limits. Ditto HTML HTML and/or HTML BODY limits. In all cases, HTML IMG appears to have a mind of its own, and will limit itself, especially vertically, solely with respect to the image itself, not any HTML container.

How to train HTML IMG to function as per container and/or window size? Would be grateful for actual examples not just suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`img { width:100%; height: auto; }` will flex your image to the size of your container, be it your image container or document. Setting `max-width` and `min-width` will constraint the image to the sizes you want.

Here is a demo

http://jsfiddle.net/T6PvL/

Just push the result window so you can see how the image flexes. If you want to set a size constraint simply state `img { max-width:300px /*or any other size you like */` and the image will only go as far as you tell it to.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need; the moon JPG confined in a box that itself is a subset of the visible window. I've captured the XHTML source and will study it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help. Please take a look at www.discoverydata.net84.net and click on foo.xhtml. Although foo.xhtml has the IMG CSS that you recommend, with IE 9.0 there is neither horizontal nor vertical constraint of IMG inside TABLE inside BODY, and with Safari 5.1.2 there is horizontal constraint [and resize] but no vertical constraint. Curiously, with a local copy of foo.xhtml and the two images, IE 9.0 and Safari 5.1.2 behave the same, i.e., horizontal but not vertical constraint. Why is the IMG CSS disregarded? Thanks.

Comment: @FrankNatoli would have to test at home, i only have Safari 4 and IE8 in my work machine and in both cases the images resized proportionally to the browser as expected.

Comment: So when you click on foo.xhtml, with Safari 4 and/or IE8, you see no horizontal or vertical scroll bars? You see both images, you see the caption below the two images, and you see the three HTML buttons below the caption, all visible without any scrolling? Incredibe!

Comment: I've implemented a JavaScript that is invoked by onload and onresize to resize the paired images in my table, keeping the table nicely within the pixel dimensions of the physical display. I know it doesn't handle resize that increases the window dimensions; just a little lazy. See www.discoverydata.net84.net and click on foo.htm. For some reason, the original implementation, photo_p93.xhtml, which of course is xhtml not htm, doesn't work, but this appears to be an artifact of the webhost. photo_p3.xhtml works perfectly as a local file on my laptop, both for IE9 and Safare 5.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be needing to subscribe to the resize event of the window. Here is a code snippet. Each time the window resizes it is triggered. This script just sets the new dimensions into the spans

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(function () {
        $(window).resize(function (e, e1) {
            $("#wWidth").text($(window).width());
            $("#wHeight").text($(window).height());
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
<span id="wWidth"></span>
<span id="wHeight"></span>
```

**Edit:**

Check out the live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Isis/vSm8h/)

**Edit:**
Resize the window in order to see the example at work.